# How to connect a multi-user Android client to connect to Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, backend, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I've been reading through developers.google for a few days now and this process is still confusing me.

As far as I can tell, I need the following:

- An Android application
- A Java App-Engine backend that uses Endpoints (still not quite
  understanding what these are).
- Code within this backend that connects to my Cloud SQL instance.

My problem is that none of Google's examples seem to have an Android/Cloud-SQL example.

I've been using [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial) on how to create an Android app with App Engine backend. But then it uses Google datastore stuff, I think? I need to use SQL rather than this.

In [this guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/) there is mention of App Engine, but for a JSP web form front-end, and no mention of Endpoints.

So my questions boils down to, have I got the right idea with using EndPoints + Cloud SQL, and if yes, how does one achieve this? I'm quite a JDBC newbie in general, so I'm not quite sure how to achieve this off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are on the right track.

Just for the record, if you don't have strong reasons (yet) to go for a SQL data store, do consider using Google Data Store as it is better seamlessly integrated into the SDKs and after a couple of compromises it should help you pushing your data design to scale nicer.

Let's split it into parts:

1. First you have your backend/api. This is basically your piece of code that operates on Google servers, which you'll access on an remote connection basis (http, socket, etc) - (same as most of the APIs we know work). I don't know which programming language you are using but here is some basic set up for [your project](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction) and [Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/) on Python.
2. Cloud Endpoints is nothing more than a very cool feature that App Engine brought recently to avoid all the mess of creating and updating your client libs over and over again. It basically automates that task for you, by using annotations or references you put in your backend code to create client libraries for Java, Objective-C and JavaScript that you can then integrate into your clients.

   Example: Let's say I have a controller on my api to operate with bananas, that has a method to delete a banana from the api. Annotating that method on your api code, will let endpoints script know that this methods is there to delete bananas, thus it'll gather it and include it in the generated clients libraries, so that you don't have to do that manually for any of your clients, nor every time you update you api code. [Here's] some documentation.
3. Android Application. That's certainly your business :) But I'm sure having your api libs already generated already helps a lot.

Hope it helps. Let me know if you need to get more into detail.

Comment: I should've made clear, my backend is Java. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It certainly has given me confidence. I still think I'm going to implement Cloud SQL. Now I'm simply not sure which Google Data Store code to remove from Endpoints, and replace with SQL code.

Also, I thought the backend/api you speak of was endpoints? So I have User.java + UserEndpoint.java for example. Is there another Java class on the backend that I've overlooked? Thanks again.

Comment: The endpoints (or controllers/methods on your backend) are just the entry point for a request to get or push data to your server. A typical structure of code within one of those methods is (body parameter validation / data store calls / data processing if necessary  / serialization). If you are using Cloud SQL it's just the part of "data store calls" the one you need to change or perform using Cloud SQL. https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/getting-started

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not precisely an expert on App Engine with Java :) but it seems what you say is right. Model and controller is all you need. I think I normally refer as "Controller" to what you call "Endpoint". We are actually speaking about the same thing. Here's a basic example for reference. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java/tree/master/src